# Syntax error in Python IDLE when trying to call a function

Tags: python, function

I am learning Python code. When I create a function it works fine but when I go to call the function I get a syntax error, what is wrong with my code?

```
    >>> def someFunction(a,b):
            print (a+b)
       someFunction(12,451)
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you find Cyber's answer fixes the problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer and up-vote it (assuming you have enough reputation to do so).

Comment: @NoctisSkytower I have marked it as the correct answer but do not yet have enough reputation to mark it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hit enter one more time after your print statement, it thinks your function call was part of the function definition. You'll know when you completed the function definition when it prompts you for a new statement with

```
>>>
```

So it would look like

```
>>> def someFunction(a,b):
        print (a+b)

>>> someFunction(12,451)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem!

Comment: @SeanLloyd note that this is specific to IDLE. If you were entering your code in a `.py` file and running it, it would execute just fine.